# Istio is not starting up due to insufficient memory in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, istio

I have setup Minikube on my macbook pro laptop.

Docker Community Edition Version 18.06.1-ce-mac73
Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6
Istio 1.0.3 release

```
$ minikube version
minikube version: v0.30.0


$ minikube update-check
CurrentVersion: v0.30.0
LatestVersion: v0.30.0


$ helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system \
  --set security.enabled=false \
  --set ingress.enabled=false \
  --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.enabled=false \
  --set gateways.istio-egressgateway.enabled=false \
  --set galley.enabled=false \
  --set sidecarInjectorWebhook.enabled=false \
  --set mixer.enabled=false \
  --set prometheus.enabled=false \
  --set global.proxy.envoyStatsd.enabled=false \
  --set pilot.sidecar=false > $HOME/istio-minimal.yaml

$ kubectl create namespace istio-system

$ kubectl apply -f $HOME/istio-minimal.yaml
```

However, when I check the pods, only 1 pod (containing pilot) is running.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n istio-system
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-pilot-d786445f4-sz9sn   0/1     Pending   0          16m
```

[image]

My laptop has 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I read the ideas at https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/567

I recreated my minikube VM. These instructions worked for me:

```
$ minikube stop
$ minikube delete
$ minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit --memory 4096
```

and I did the rest of the steps in the original post to start istio. This time pilot pod did successfully come.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n istio-system
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-pilot-d786445f4-ndxnd   1/1     Running   0          13m
```

However, I am not sure why mixer and citadel didn't come up.

Comment: It was on documentation here https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/platform-setup/minikube/

"To install Istio control plane components and addons, as well as other applications, we recommend starting Minikube with 8192 MB of memory and 4 CPUs."

I also faced this issue, raised vm memory to 4096 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Istio requires 16GB of memory, then you have to specify something like this:

```
$ minikube start --memory=16384 --cpus=4 --kubernetes-version=v1.20.2
```

If you don't set the `--memory=` flag, then the default value is 2GB.

More information [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/minikube/#:%7E:text=Start%20minikube%20with%2016384%20MB)